# Application crashes with error could not create ssl/tls secure channel

Tags: ssl, tls, c#

I contacted the customer care and this is what they have to say -

*kindly make sure that the SSL certificate used for the SMTP service offered by the Microsoft Exchange Server is not expired and the SSL certificate used for the SMTP service offered by the Microsoft Exchange Server match the hostname you are using. Please make sure that the SSL certificate used for the SMTP service offered by the Microsoft Exchange Server is not revoked*

Image of the error
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WrWO.jpg) -

The detailed error logs are here -
https://pastebin.com/pjeSr9WC

Comment: What application?

Comment: It is a trading software called Pi.